# iOS notification for built-in timer app "stop playing"

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, notifications

My radio app support background play, base on AVPlayer and AVAudioSession.

Some user said: The iOS timer app "Stop Playing" should stop the audio.

I have no idea to detect timer app trigger.

Any idea?

I tried AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification, but nothing happen.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found it.

When built-in timer app countdown to zero,it will trigger the `remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:`
and the event.subtype is UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop